# Difficulty Storing Timestamp in Store Using Core Data and Retrieving Consistent Values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, core-data, nsnumber

Hey guys, I am storing a time stamp in my iPhone app via Core Data, I have had success doing it in the past storing a double value as an INT 64 type in Core Data. However, I just recently had to change it to an NSNumber instance instead of a primitive double type and ever since I have not been able to get Core Data to store and retrieve the same numeric value (the following are attempts with different numeric attribute types within Core Data):

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code that generates this console output is the following:

```
NSLog(@"VALUE BEING STORED: %@",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tmeStmp]);
[[CoreDataSingleton sharedManager] setItemInDFMWhilePreservingEntityUniquenessForItem:timeStampAttr withValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tmeStmp]];
[[CoreDataSingleton sharedManager] saveStore];
NSLog(@"VALUE RETRIEVED FROM STORE: %@",[[CoreDataSingleton sharedManager] getTimeStamp]);
```

Relevant parts of `setItemInDFMWhilePreservingEntityUniquenessForItem:withValue:`:

```
-(void)setItemInDFMWhilePreservingEntityUniquenessForItem:(attribute)attr withValue:(id)value {
//...
        } else if (attr == timeStampAttr) {
            [dfm setTimeStamp:value];
        }
//...
            } else if (attr == timeStampAttr) {
                [[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0] setTimeStamp:value];
            }
//...
}
```

Relevant parts of `getTimeStamp`:

```
-(NSNumber *)getTimeStamp {
//...
NSNumber *returnable = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:(NSInteger)[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"]] autorelease];
return returnable;
}
```

I am thinking that I am most likely not converting between numeric types adequately, but I have fudged around with the code for hours with no luck. Any idea where I am going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you are not storing the time stamps as dates?

Comment: Umm, not really. I just started storing double timestamps and that was working fine and dandy until I needed to expand and improve my code, which forced me to use NSNumber instances, and now I am getting problems. If I can't find an easy fix soon I will just do as you suggest.

Comment: I think you are having a conceptual problem with NSNumber. You keep wanting to treat it like a scalar value when it is a full fledged object. If you were storing the integers/doubles before in Core Data you were using NSNumbers to do so. An `Int64` type in Core Data is represented by an NSNumber so your previous code must have had proper NSNumber handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I just figured it out (came back to it after some time). This line (in `getTimeStamp`):

```
NSNumber *returnable = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:(NSInteger)[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"]] autorelease];
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
NSNumber *returnable = [[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

I guess I was expecting NSNumber to have an initArrayWithArray type of method, but it doesn't so it was causing problems. I retain this return value in the calling function so all is good and well. Hope this helps others stuck on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you starting with a cast of NSInteger in your getTimeStamp function? You can store the timestamp as a number, using NSNumber.

for example, I do something similar in my code, using the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, but I think the application is the same:

```
    action.ID=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
    NSLog(@"action ID=%F",[action.ID doubleValue]);
```

At one point, I thought perhaps the value wasn't being stored properly, but when I changed the format string to %lf, things came out the way I wanted.

Does this help, or miss the mark?

Comment: I tried changing the cast to an NSNumber but it gives me the error: 'Conversion to non-scalar type requested' and I need a cast to something as value is merely an id in that function and the compiler complains in anycase.

Answer (score 0):

All numberical values returned from Core Data come packaged as NSNumber instances. So, this line:

```
NSNumber *returnable = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:(NSInteger)[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"]] autorelease];
```

... won't retrieve the correct value because this part:

```
[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"timeStamp"]
```

... returns an NSNumber instance which you then cast to a NSInteger. Of course, this means casting the memory address of the object to an integer which produces a nonsense value.

With the exception of `Decimal`, the numerical types that you set in the data model are just for use by the store. From the perspective of managed objects, all numbers are NSNumber objects.

As an aside, this code all seems unnecessarily complex. Why are you storing time stamps as numerical info instead of dates? Why the multiple steps to access small pieces of data? You might want to simplify if possible.

Comment: You recommend merely storing the timestamp as an NSDate and do whatever conversion I need to while in memory? I may just end up doing that. See my comment to the other answer though as that is what I am currently stuck on. Thanks.